# How do I detect a touch in navigationController.view?

Tags: ios, swift, layer

I was implementing this function.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self.view) else { return }

    for i in 0..<paths.count {
        if paths[i].contains(point) { addViews(selectedView: i); break }
    }
}
```

My designers decided they want to make a small part of the views I add to overlay the navigationBar. The problem is that after I add the views to the navigationController.view instead, I am no longer able to detect the touches. I have tried location(in: self.navigationController.view) and that didn't work. Before I go down the rabbit hole of endless different things that might work, does anyone have an easy answer for me?
[image: navigationBar overlay example]

Answer (score 0):

While navigationController is nominally a ViewController, it's 'view' outlet is usually not used, and probably not put in the responder chain.

My solution was to create a custom view (in the storyboard) as outlet for navigationItem.titleView for the UIViewController.

You can set up the custom view in viewDidLoad() (instead of storyboard)

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = myCustomView;
```

In viewDidLoad I set up a gesture like:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleStatusTap:)];
[chatTitleView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: I should have been more explicit. TapRecognizers only work with views and I specifically am using a UIBezierPath to detect the tap because they are several layers within the same view. I'll edit and post a picture so it's easier to understand.

Comment: Cool, I might try to move the layers back to the viewController.view and either hide the nav bar, or remove the viewController from the navigationController.